# C# webrequest problems

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i'm having a bit of an issue when trying to create a WebRequest for Windows Phone 7.

When I try following the code examples from MSDN, it keeps saying to do this:

```
Stream data = response.GetRequesteStream;
```

But when i type that into Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone, I get a red squiggly line and an error message stating:

```
System.Net.WebRequest does not contain a reference for "GetRequestStream" 
and no extention method "GetRequestStream" accepting a first argument of 
type 'System.Net.WebRequest' could be found
```

Any ideas as to what's going on? It seems as though I'm missing an actual method...but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone doesn't support many (most) synchronous APIs.  You must use the asynchronous [`BeginGetRequestStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method.

There are probably plenty more online, but one example of usage for the Phone [can be found here](http://alpascual.com/post/my-first-windows-phone-7-application.aspx).

Comment: Ahh, okay that clears it up. I wasn't aware that Windows Phone didn't support many synchronous API's